# Prove that $a=1+b$ if the points $(a,b);(b,a);(a^2,-b^2)$ are collinear

Tags: analytic-geometry

Area of triangle formed by the points will be zero

$$0=a(a+b^2)+b(-b^2-b)+a^2(b-a)$$
$$a^2+ab^2-b^3-b^2+a^2b-a^3=0$$
$$a^2-b^2-(a^3+b^3)+ab(a+b)=0$$
$$(a+b)(a-b)-(a+b)(a^2+b^2-ab)+ab(a+b)=0$$
From here I get $a+b=0$

What’s going wrong?

Comment: Why not using that the straight line through $a$ and $b$ has the equation $$y-b=\frac{b-a}{a-b}(x-a)\iff y=-x+1+2b$$ and then plug in $x=a^2=(1+b)^2$ to get painlessly $y=-b^2$?

Answer (score 1):

You've excluded the other factor

Assuming $a\ne b$

$$\dfrac{b-a}{a-b}=-1$$

We need $$\dfrac{b+b^2}{a-a^2}=-1$$

$$\iff0= b+a+b^2-a^2=(b+a)(1+b-a)$$

Comment: so $a=1+b$  or $-b$

Comment: @JWTanner, Yes, so $a=1+b$ is a sufficient condition for collinearity, but not necessary

Comment: Why $\frac{b+b^2}{a-a^2}=-1$~

Comment: @Aditya:  because the slope of the line containing $(a,b)$ and $(a^2,-b^2)$ must equal the slope of the line containing $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$